# Node Express on Heroku, service time spiking

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I've got a Node application running on Heroku serving out web content and acting as an REST API endpoint, both using node-express. The issue I'm seeing is that occasionally service times are spiking dramatically. (Sometimes to 20000+ms, up from, say, 50ms.) This seems to be happening both on occasional static file loads, as well as a very simple API call that provides a heartbeat connection to active pages. These spikes are happening on a very small percentage of overall page-loads (<1%), so I'm having trouble duplicating them myself.

For example:

`heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/static/js/thirdparty/jquery.min.js" host=somehost request_id=c1a88972-ba1b-4861-80c3-d8949fc1aa24 fwd="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=64ms service=9560ms status=200 bytes=96677`

Or, in the case of the API call:

`2014-10-25T01:33:39.360282+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=POST path="/heartbeat/" host=somehost request_id=4b35cac3-b726-460d-a7fe-6cfc622b8b1c fwd="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6962ms status=200 bytes=167`

I'm at a loss for how to properly diagnose this. I'm running a single dyno currently, so my best guess is *something* is locking up the dyno. I'm not yet in production, and even then expect my level of traffic to be quite low – nothing that broadly justifies having multiple simultaneous dynos running at any given time. When I've tried to step through my code and add logs on the server-side, I've never seen anything running slowly on my side. I appreciate that there could be a number of variables in my code that cause this – some occasional hiccup in my heartbeat that delays the response. But that doesn't explain why I'm also seeing it in the files served statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mentioning here that you're using node + express -- since node applications are only running in a single thread, the likely culprit here is that your application is doing something which is locking up the CPU.

The reason I know this is that your connect time is only 64ms here (this is the amount of time it took for the user's request to get from the load balancer to your dyno) -- but the service time itself is 9560ms -- this means almost all the processing time was taking place in your application code.